# Bind an array to the parent of an angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I am having an issue on implementing two-way binding on a child component.  So my goal would be for when an array gets a new object added/removed, the array on the parent component would also reflect that change.  Here is some code to better detail.

Parent component controller:

```
export class ParentController {
    selectedItems = [];
}
```

parent component html:

```
<list-selector selectedItems="$ctrl.selectedItems"></list-selector>
```

child component:

```
export var listSelectorComponent: IComponentOptions = {
    bindings: {
        selectedItems: "="
    },
    controller: childController
};
```

child controller:

```
export class listSelectorController {

    selectedItems = [];

    addToSelectedItems(){
        this.selectedItems.push({name:'First Item'});
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting.  I am pretty sure it has to do with the binding, but I am not sure what is wrong.  Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'selectedItems' used with directive 'listSelector' is non-assignable!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is indeed with your binding.
Just change your parent component html to:

```
<list-selector selected-items="$ctrl.selectedItems"></list-selector>
```

And you're good to go.
Note that the html tag attributes must be `like-this` while the binding property must always be camelcase `likeThis`.